# W. Rudin, POMA, Ch 1, Ex 6

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving

Fix $b>1$.

Let's define $B(x)=\{b^t:t\in \mathbb{Q},t\leq x\}$.

Prove that $b^r=\sup B(r)$ when $r$ is rational. Hence it makes sense to define $b^x=\sup B(x)$ for every real $x$.

The question is about last sentence: "Hence it makes sense to define $b^x=\sup B(x)$ for every real $x$."

Can someone explain rigorously how our prove for rational $x$ makes sense define it for real $x$?

I think it is because the real line is complete and that rational numbers are dense in real line. But I dont know how to show it rigorously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that "the real line is complete and the rational numbers are dense in the real line" perhaps helps to justify that the definition of $b^x$ over $x \in \mathbb{R}$ matches our visual intuitive picture of what the graph of an exponential function should look like; but that is *not* what is needed here just for the definition to "make sense" - you are overcomplicating things!

---

For any $b>0$ and any rational $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, we already have a definition of $b^x$. With this, for any $b>0$ and any real $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we can define a set $B(x)$ by
$$ B(x) := \{b^t : t \in \mathbb{Q}, t \leq x\}\text{.} $$
It is easy to check that for any real $x$, the set $B(x)$ is bounded above, and therefore $\,\sup B(x)\,$ is a well-defined real number!

In the case that $x$ is rational, this number $\,\sup B(x)\,$ turns out to be precisely the value of $b^x$. Therefore, *it would not create any inconsistency of definitions* to introduce a definition of $b^x$ for all real $x$ as
$$ b^x := \sup B(x)\text{,} $$
since those $x$-values for which $b^x$ has already been defined (namely, the rationals) give the same value for $b^x$ under our previously-existing definition (defined only for rational $x$) as under our new definition (defined for all real $x$).

Comment: *It is easy to check that for any real x, the set B(x) is bounded above...* How? We know that for $a>c \implies b^a>b^c$ because $b>1$. Then we can choose any rational $p>x$ for which $b^p>b^t$ where $t\leq x$? Is it correct?

Comment: *In the case that x is rational, this number supB(x) turns out to be precisely the value of b^x. * I understand this. But I dont understand what happens when x is irrational. We have just written down that its supremum will be $b^x$. But why we not prove it? Or it is obvious?

Comment: Your argument that $B(x)$ is bounded above is correct! Well done! You say, "But I don't understand what happens when $x$ is irrational. We have just written down that its supremum will be $b^x$. But why do we not prove it? Or is it obvious?" You have misunderstood the aim of the task: it is to **define** $b^x$ when $x$ is irrational! Rudin is seeking to build up the definitions of all these concepts from scratch; you do *not* already have a concept of $b^x$ for irrational $x$ before this point!

Comment: At high school, you work with these kinds of concepts on the basis of pictures and visual intuition. But in rigorous mathematics (which, in mathematics education, generally begins at undergraduate university level), you cannot simply assume that the pictures and visual intuitions are valid, and so you need to re-build these concepts from scratch without reliance on visual intuitions that essentially come from experience rather than logical deduction, and which accordingly may be wrong.

Comment: [For example, a school pupil's "experience" will suggest to him/her that in the graph of a continuous function, differentiable sections of the curve will fill out a dense subset of the curve, with the remaining nowhere-dense set of points being either corner-points (i.e. points with well-defined but distinct left- and right-sided derivatives) or accumulation points of corner points. But Weierstrass proved this wrong. For example, a 1-dimensional Brownian motion is a continuous motion, but at each instant in time there is no well-defined answer as to whether it is moving left or right.]

Comment: Thanks! I understand now

Comment: Is there any book which you can recomend to study in real analysis. I read Rudin but at first glance the material from a chapter is not sufficient to solve the problems. Or it does not depend on a textbook and I must try to solve?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not an expert on real analysis textbooks, but I would expect that the problems in Rudin are meant to be solvable just using the material in Rudin (plus maybe some things from high-school mathematics).